# I want to point my website DNS to another server on AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-route53

I have 1 hosted zone on Route 53 and have 2 server instances in EC2, one a Windows instance and the other, a Ubuntu instance. I launched the Ubuntu instance and uploaded my website to the proper folders and everything looks good. Now I wish to shutdown the windows instance but need the DNS server to point to my other instance? How to I do that?

I am guessing that I have to enter the Ubuntu instance details in my Route 53?
[Snippet of Route 53 details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O5oX.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update "A" record entries with "Windows" instance public DNS IP (or) Elastic IP (Don't need to modify any NS or SOA) records. That should switch traffic to new box. Note that if you are NOT using Elastic IP, every time you restart (as commented by Sathed, it is shutdown and startup) "instance" you will get new public IP, which you would need to update in Route53 records.

Make sure to have proper security groups applied.

Comment: Just "restarting" the instance won't pull a new public IP. However, performing a complete shutdown/startup will pull a new public IP.

Comment: @Sathed: Most of the times I tried, shutdown and startup, which might be the reason why I saw new public IP. Updated answer with your comment to be more specific. Thanks!

Comment: I am in Route 53 and editing the A Record...my *new* Ubuntu instance does not have a valid s3 endpoint? All the Ubuntu instance has is a Public IP that starts with ec2-**-***-***-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com?

Comment: @Kimosabe2016 Not sure what your comment is about? If new issue, please post new question.

Comment: Hi Nambari! This is not a new issue...just the same as above. In regards to your post above where you say: "Update "A" record entries with "Windows" instance public DNS IP (or) Elastic IP (Don't need to modify any NS or SOA) records." I am in Route 53 and trying to figure out what and what to change. I am online right now.

Comment: @Nambari Shouldn't I attach my storage and point it to the Windows S3 bucket? When I'm trying to "Update the A record" it requires a S3 endpoint?